# disable a thread on click

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on app that calculate time when specific app run, to save ram, I want to stop some of the threads by using check box. i want a command when I press the check box the thread stops even "if condition" is right"

the if conditon of detecting app :

```
if (MainActivity.tgbutton.isChecked())
{
    if (packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana"))
    {

        if (f==1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fb on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            f=1;
            facebook = true;
            startTimef = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandlerf.postDelayed(updateTimerThreadfacebook, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(f==1)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fb off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            facebook = false;
            timeSwapBufff += timeInMillisecondsf;

            customHandlerf.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThreadfacebook);
            f=2;
        }
    }
}
```

the check box :

```
blabla.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

            // what to write here to disable thread???
        }

    }
});
```

the thread itself :

```
private Runnable updateTimerThreadfacebook = new Runnable() {


    public void run() {


        if (facebook = true)
        {
            timeInMillisecondsf = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTimef;

            updatedTimef = timeSwapBufff + timeInMillisecondsf;

            int secsf = (int) (updatedTimef / 1000);
            int minsf = secsf / 60;
            secsf = secsf % 60;

            MainActivity.facebook.setText("" + minsf + ":" + String.format("%02d", secsf));

            customHandlerf.postDelayed(this, 0);

        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I don't see any thread code but here  `customHandlerf.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThreadfacebook);`

Answer (score 1):

you should use value on your run method

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable{
boolean signal=false;
public setisFinish(boolean sig)
{
    signal = sig;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
  if(!signal)
  //Do SomeThing
}

public void foo()
{
    System.out.println("foo");
}
```

}

and in your click listener

```
blabla.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

       myThread.setisFinish(true);
    }

}
```

});

this code resume your thread and you can start it whenever you whant and if you want interrupt your thread use this code

```
myThread.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrap your Runnable object with Thread class:

```
    private Thread updateTimerThreadfacebook = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (facebook = true) {
                timeInMillisecondsf = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTimef;

                updatedTimef = timeSwapBufff + timeInMillisecondsf;

                int secsf = (int) (updatedTimef / 1000);
                int minsf = secsf / 60;
                secsf = secsf % 60;

                MainActivity.facebook.setText("" + minsf + ":" + String.format("%02d", secsf));
                customHandlerf.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

when you want to stop it use *interrupt* method.

```
updateTimerThreadfacebook.interrupt();
```